# WindowsPhone MediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, playback, mediaelement

In my application I have one MediaElement per page. When navigated to this page I play a voice message.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
      mediaElement.Stop();
      smediaElement.Source = new Uri("res/sounds/" + soundName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

I have registered lsitener MediaOpened for MediaElement:

```
private void me_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        MediaElement m = (MediaElement)sender;
        m.Play();
}
```

But the sound is playing only on **every other** page. 

So it looks like: Page1 (sound) -> Page2 (no sound) -> Page3 (sound) -> Page4 (not sound).

 I tried everything and I can't figure what can cause such behaviour. Maybe it is not important but I'm navigateing through instances of the same PhoneApplicationPage subclass. 

 Any ideas?

P

Comment: have you tried handling the `MediaFailed` event to see if there's an exception? Is the opened event being called on the pages where the sound isn't being played?

Comment: Good point. I will try Media Failed. Opened event is not being called on the pages where the sound isn't being played.

Comment: is it the same sound played by every page? Does that sound finish playing before navigating to the next page? Do you stop the currently playign sound when navigating off a page?

Comment: it is not the same sound. I stop previous sound in navigateFrom method.

Comment: I checked and registered listener onMediaFailed. This event is fired and error message is "3123 An error has occurred."

Comment: does the error have a call stack that may be more helpful? Is it always the alternate calls that fail? even if you change the tracks that are played by each page?

Comment: the error doens't have a call stack. I already tried change the track. It is always on every other page. Sound is playing (doesnt matter which file i choose) on pages 1, 3, 5, .. and is not playing on pages 2, 4, 6,.. I tried already open media element again in OnMediaFailed function. It works at some point. The sound was playing on each page, unless I clicked back button. No sound at all was playing therefore.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I'v even tried remove MediaElement from Page in onNavigatedFrom, so there shouldn't be two media element existing at the same time. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem generating MediaElement dynamically and removing from layout in onNavigatedFrom 
here is code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        mediaElement = new MediaElement();
        slideSound.Volume = 1;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mediaElement);
        ....
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        mediaElement.Stop();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(mediaElement);
        mediaElement = null;
}
```

It works perfectly. It is quite werid that you have to remove mediaElement from page or on the next page playing sound will be not working corectly.

Comment: As an alternative, you could create a single `MediaElement` at app level and have each page update what is played there, rather than creating a new instance on each page.